# How to add formula in xlsx file using xlsx_builder_package

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql

I am preparing excel file using xlsx_builder_pkg library. But I didn't find the way.
How can I add formula to cell in xlsx file using xlsx_builder package?

Thanks
Nidhi

Comment: [XLSX_BUILDER_PKG](https://github.com/commi235/xlsx_builder) is not a built-in Oracle library.

Comment: xlsx_builder is a third-party product which allows us to export data in the proprietary MS Excel format. It does not reproduce all the functionality of Excel. This means it does not support formulas. However, a formula is just a device for deriving a cell value from other cells in the spreadsheet. You can do this using PL/SQL or SQL when you extract the data or elsewhere in your program.